# How can I do a console log every X seconds in the background of my application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I want to basically do a backup every X minutes, but let's for simplicity's sake say I want to just console log something or do some async stuff. It should run in the background and not block the rest of my app. Any advice?

Comment: `setInterval(() => console.log('hello'), 60000) // once a minute (roughly)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use     `setInterval` in `componentDidMount` and you can change `1000` to a variable.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => console.log("here"), 1000 );
      }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```